# Limit Gen.posNum to be within a range

Tags: specs2, scalacheck

I am building an `Arbitrary[Source]` in my specification like so:

```
implicit def arbSource = Arbitrary {
  for {
    i: Int <- Gen.posNum[Int]
    ss: List[String] <- Gen.listOfN(i, Gen.alphaStr)
  } yield Source.fromString(ss.mkString("\n"))
}
```

How can I make the follow check pass? (i.e. how to limit `i` to be within a range)

```
def test = arbSource{s => s.getLines().toSeq.size must beBetween(1, 200)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Gen.choose(min, max)` instead of `Gen.posNum[Int]`.